# Не работает 3-уровневое выпадающее меню на Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, меню

Не работает 3-уровневое выпадающее меню на Bootstrap — в чём может быть проблема (2 работают отлично)?

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">СВАДЕБНАЯ ФЛОРИСТИКА <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="../buketi.php">БУКЕТЫ</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="../dekorirovanie_butilok.php">ДЕКОРИРОВАНИЕ БУТЫЛОК</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="../kompozicii.php">КОМПОЗИЦИИ</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#">ОФОРМЛЕННЫЕ СВАДЬБЫ </a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="../n1.php">№1</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="../n2.php">№2</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
    </li>

  </ul>
  <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в версии bootstrap. Твой код будет рабоать в boostrap2. Но многоуровневое меню было удалено из boostrap3 (из соображений что многоуровеневое меню есть зло, см. линк ниже). Дубликат вопроса на английском:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing

Там же приводится ссылка на несколько CSS строчек для bootstrap3 которые надо добавить, чтобы это заработало как раньше:

http://www.bootply.com/86684